# Book Now or Wait

Tags: air-travel, bookings, new-york-city, british-airways, philadelphia

I am travelling from Bologna to Philadelphia on Feb. 28 and then back to Bologna from New York on May 4. Currently, the price is 458 Euro for British Airways. However, many online forums say that flights are usually cheaper on Sunday or Tuesday. Can anybody who travelled on this route tell if this price is reasonable or not? Are there good chances that I can get a lower price than this?

Comment: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/news/Never-book-flights-on-Fridays-and-eight-other-tips-for-getting-cheap-air-fares/

Comment: http://www.farecompare.com/travel-advice/tips-from-air-travel-insiders/#/

Comment: For crossing the Atlantic that's already a pretty good price. I probably wouldn't bother shopping further.

Comment: Second @MichaelHampton you've likely hit the best price at two weeks away from departure; grab it.

Comment: Is your return from Philadelphia through New York to Bologna? Or your itinerary is Bologna to Philadelphia then on the return you fly straight out of New York?

Comment: Bologna - Philadelphia

Comment: But I will return from New York

Comment: You might try using the same airport (Philly or New York) on both ends and see if that helps.  The cities are less than two hours apart by rail.  Also make sure to check both EWR and JFK.

Comment: What a shame to miss two months of life, in Bologna!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When studies show that flights are GENERALLY lower on Tuesday (I have not heard of Sunday), that determination is based on analyzing large quantities of data.

All that tells you is that on average prices on those days are lower and over the long run assuming you purchased tickets every day, you will get lower prices on those days.

However for ONE event, that is you buying your ONE ticket for ONE particular time, that data only gives you some probability. It does not do anything more than that.

In your case, with the kind of transatlantic flight route you are flying, unless you catch one of those smashing $100 for one way sales on flights like WOWAIR or Norwegian, you're not going to beat €458 **by much**. Plus those flights you typically have to pay more for baggage.

You have a quite decent deal. BA in the USA has free 24 hour cancellation. You can book today and check prices tomorrow which is a Sunday, if it's cheaper you can cancel the ticket you bought today and rebook for tomorrow at the cheaper price.In any case if you want to roll the dice, the price change between now and Tuesday wont likely be much because today till Tuesday are both just outside the **two week window** to departure.